# Is it correct to say you're trying to protect yourself from or against something?

Tags: phrasing

For example: *"I'm trying to protect myself from the brainwashing aliens."*

My idea is that **against** seems like a stronger word to me. Making the item or topic at hand seem more... how should I say... of a negative thing? Not clear. But I also know it's more common for people to say, for example "I'm trying to protect myself **from** you/the aliens."

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Makes sense. Looking there, now.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether or not there is an object. So in this case: "I'm trying to protect myself from the brainwashing aliens." the object would be *myself*. This usage is correct.

[WITH OBJECT]
‘he tried to protect Kelly from the attack’
[no object] ‘use a sunscreen that protects against both UVA and UVB’
Source: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/protect

For example, you could say:

(**a**) ‘use a sunscreen that protects against both UVA and UVB’
(**b**) ‘use a sunscreen that protects your skin from both UVA and UVB’

In (**a**) there is no object, but in (**b**) the object is *your skin*.